# how do i convert 24hrs time variable in R to carry out regression models?

Tags: r

I want to carry our a logistic regression for repeated measures in `R` . I want to check whether the time of last meal of the day differs in depressed and non-depressed kids. i have recordings of mealtime over a period of 14 days for all subjects (dep/non-dep).
The only trouble Im having is converting these time variables into an appropriate form to carry our the analysis. Converting them to decimal numbers( eg. 15.5) doesnt seem like a good idea.. Please help!

```
id  depressed mealtime     
B8         1 17:30:00       
B8         1 17:00:00      
B8         1 12:30:00      
B8         1     <NA>         
B8         1 19:45:00       
B8         1 19:30:00       
A1         0 19:30:00       
A1         0 18:45:00      
A1         0 19:30:00      
A1         0 18:30:00       
A1         0 20:30:00
```

Comment: What is the class of mealtime?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to convert your mealtime variable to a difference time with a reference point? For example using `strptime` to cooerce your string to `POSIXlt` and `difftime` you can do something like:

```
dat$mealtime <- strptime(dat$mealtime,'%H:%M:%S')
dat$difference <- difftime(dat$mealtime,time2=strptime('00:00:00','%H:%M:%S'))
```

Now , you can use the new created variable for your regression, (I assume you `glm` for your logit)

```
fit <- glm(depressed ~ difference,data=dat, family=binomial("logit"))
```

*PS*: Here dat is :

```
dat <- read.table(text='id  depressed mealtime     
B8         1 17:30:00       
B8         1 17:00:00      
B8         1 12:30:00      
B8         1     <NA>         
B8         1 19:45:00       
B8         1 19:30:00       
A1         0 19:30:00       
A1         0 18:45:00      
A1         0 19:30:00      
A1         0 18:30:00       
A1         0 20:30:00',header=TRUE)
```

Comment: okay well i tried doing this and it worked perfectly, i  dont understand what dat$mealtime and dat$differnce are doing exactly. like what form are the new variables. I dont know how to interpret the beta values . like the beta estimate for difference  is -0.06. would that mean that depressed kid tend to eat 0.06 hrs before non depressed kids? ..sorry im just really new to this...thanks in advance

Comment: dat$mealtime : access the variable mealtime ...it is equivalent to dat[,3]( acces the third column)... I just create new variable difference( it is the number of hours ...). I am not statistician, I never do a logit estimation. SO i can't help you for the interpretation.